# How to fix InvalidInput error code (missing value for timestamp type) to createFulfillmentOrder in AWS SP-SPI?

Tags: php, json, amazon-selling-partner-api

I've encountered problem while developing order creation logic for amazon sp-api.

This is request body:

```
{
    "sellerFulfillmentOrderId": "PEER1681558668",
    "displayableOrderId": "PEER1681558668",
    "displayableOrderDate": "2023-04-15T11:37:48Z",
    "displayableOrderComment": "Thank you.",
    "shippingSpeedCategory": "Standard",
    "destinationAddress": {
        "name": "john",
        "addressLine1": "Some_Address",
        "city": "Greensboro",
        "stateOrRegion": "NC",
        "countryCode": "US",
        "postalCode": "27400"
    },
    "items": [
        {
            "sellerSku": "8XXX002",
            "quantity": 1,
            "sellerFulfillmentOrderItemId": "BXXXNM5XBY"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is response body:

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "code": "InvalidInput",
            "message": "missing value for timestamp type",
            "details": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

Error code is 400 for above response.

Can anyone help?

At first site it looks like request body is correct since it works for separate github setup code. Using the same body doesn't work for new setup.
P.S.: All 'get' methods are returning proper response. This is first 'post' request i'm attempting but no luck.

Comment: Did you get any reason for this?

Comment: Hi @amithlal,
Above query was resolved after careful review of request body. Any questions on it?

Comment: ya got the same kind of error while creating new order(for some order), so i just want to know the reason

Comment: Please check with below request body:

   ['destinationAddress' => ['name' => 'adam', 'addressLine1' => 'add1', 'city' => 'city', 'stateOrRegion' => 'MA', 'countryCode' => 'US', 'postalCode' => '12345'],'displayableOrderComment' => 'HappyShopping','displayableOrderDate' => gmdate('Ymd\THis\Z',strtotime('2023-08-16')),'displayableOrderId' => 'O1','items' => [[sellerSku, quantity, sellerFulfillmentOrderItemId]],'sellerFulfillmentOrderId' => 'O1','shippingSpeedCategory' => 'Standard']

Let me know if this works.